# edit records using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am experiencing a problem editing records in a database. I have a table showing all records of cliends in the view page and next to them I have a anchor link to edit the record .

I send the id to a function of the controller called site/update and I get the id by using

```
 $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

then I send the id to the findRecord($id) model to get the records corresponding to the id in the database.

if i print_r the query i get

```
 Array ( [records] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [name] =>
 sdf [surname] => sdf [contact] => 35353 [email] => blabla@gmail.com ) ) )
```

i can print this in the controller and not in the view

How can i do it?where is the problem?

the controller code:

```
    <?php

    class Site extends CI_Controller 
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__Construct();
            $this->is_logged_in();
        }

        function members_area()
        {
            $data=array();

            if($query=$this->site_model->getrecords()){
                $data['records']=$query;
            }
            $this->load->view('logged_in_area',$data);
        }

        function add() // just for sample
        {
            $this->load->view('add_clients');
        }

        function is_logged_in()
        {
            $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
            if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
            {
                echo 'You don\'t have permission to access this page. <a href="../login">Login</a>';    
                die();      
                //$this->load->view('login_form');
            }       
        }
        function create(){
                $this->load->library('form_validation');///// form validation to add clients

            // field name, error message, validation rules
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('surname', 'Surname', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact Number', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('add_clients');
            }else{
                $data=array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                'surname'=>$this->input->post('surname'),
                'contact'=>$this->input->post('contact'),
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email'));
                $this->site_model->addRecords($data);
                $this->members_area();  
                }
        }
        function delete($id){
                $this->site_model->deleteRow($id);
                $this->members_area();
        }
        function update(){
            $data2=array();
            $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        if($query=$this->site_model->findRecord($id)){
            $data2['records']=$query;
            //print_r($data2);
            $this->load->view('logged_in_area',$data2);
                }else{echo' nothing';}
            //$this->load->model('employesModel');
            //if($t=$this->site_model->findRecord($id)){
            //$this->load->view('update_clients',$data);
            //$this->site_model->updateRecord($data,$id);
        }
    }
```

the view model

```
    <body>
        <h2 style="text-align:left">Welcome Back, <?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>!</h2>
         <p>This section represents the area that only logged in members can access.</p><br/>
         <h2>Clients List</h2>
         <?php
         if(isset($records)):
         echo'<table align="left"  width="40%" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="3" border="0">
         <tr><td align="left"><b>Name</b></td><td align="left"><b>Surname</b></td><td align="left"><b>Phone number</b></td><td align="left"><b>Email address</b></td><td>
         </td></tr>';
          foreach ($records as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->surname;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->contact;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->email;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo anchor("site/delete/$row->id",'Delete');?>&nbsp;<?php echo anchor("site/members_area/$row->id",'Update')?></td>
        </tr>
          <?php endforeach; echo '</table>'?>
          <?php else: ?>
          <h2>No records were returned</h2>
          <?php endif; ?><br/><br/><br/><br/><?php if(isset($data2))var_dump($data2);?><br/><br/>
    <p>
         <?php echo anchor('site/add','Add clients');?>&nbsp;
         <?php echo anchor('login/logout', 'Logout'); ?>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and lastly the model

```
function findRecord($id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('clients', array('id' => $id));
    return  $query->result();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the view ? Or in the source of the view ?

Comment: Well it seems that the fault is not in the code that you are displaying here.. Especially if you can get results with the print_r inside the controller.

Comment: try $row['name']..........write all other things also and let me know......

Comment: where shall i try this @Venkat ?

Comment: @Venkat - it's `std class object` not an `array`

Comment: @ak_47 - please display the result of `var_dump($records)` in your view..

Comment: nothing is displayed . AND also is not the $records i am checking is the $data2 array

Comment: so whats happening? @mamdouhalramadan

Comment: @ak_47 - I can see your foreach is looping through your $records variable which should include data and you say it has nothing in it.. that's why I asked for your var_dump... anyway. as malix said. the code your showing is fine, then, please update with more details that might be relevant to your problem.

Comment: ok I have put all the code of the controller so u can check where the problem could be @mamdouhalramadan

Comment: @ak_47 - the controller has no problem since you can print your data in it.. please show your view. most likely it has the problem

Comment: @ak_47 - please try without the `if(isset(records))`

Comment: so whats next ? @mamdouhalramadan

Comment: Sorry, But can't seem to find errors in your code here. are you sure that you are calling the right view. is there a chance that your calls has some interruptions.. and have you checked for errors even in firebug or so... there most be some logical error here.. but the code seems fine

Comment: btw. you don't need to use uri->segment - a native way would be to use the method parameter: `function update($id){...` and normally use the `$id` from there

Comment: Please look at your views source code via browser. Do you see <tr> and <td> where you want to display the results from db? Are you sure there is no error there?

Comment: I found the solution :) its working now

Comment: I had to remove the if statement from this line of code in the controller if($query=$this->site_model->findRecord($id)){

Comment: This discussion is growing too long and hard to follow. However it contains good information which should be integrated into the the question or an answer. Please do that and if needed, continue the discussion in the chat!

Comment: Did you try setting the `$query` before the if and then check it?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting any data to view file, because you aren't sending the data to it. Take a look at your code, you have a mispelling:

```
if($query**=**$this->site_model->getrecords()){
            $data['records']=$query;}
```

Try to change the = to ==.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're receiving an array within an array, try using the index of the array $records['0'] instead of $records.

```
E.g: $records['0'] as $row
```